# Kotlin if statement only returning the first if not checking else if

Tags: android, kotlin, if-statement, viewmodel

The requirements have the two first fun to be in ViewModel. val f and run are in Main Activity. The loop is stopping. I think there might be an issue toFloat(). Is there something that I am missing? Thank you for the help.

```
val f = bmiViewModel.updatebmi(bmiViewModel.formula(inc, wt, ft))
                run(f)

fun formula(inc: Int, ft: Int, wt: Int): Float {

        val htTotal = (ft*12).toFloat() + inc.toFloat()
        val BMI  = (wt.toFloat()*703) / (htTotal * htTotal)
        Log.d(TAG,"BMI", Exception())
        return BMI

fun updatebmi(total: Float): Int{

        if (total < 18.5) {
            return -256
        } else if (total >= 18.5 && total < 24.9) {
            return 8
        } else if (total >= 24.9 && total < 30) {
            return 256
        } else{
            return 16
        }
    }
private fun run(i: Int){

        if (i == -256) {
            binding.status.text = "Under Weight"
            binding.status.setTextColor(i)
        } else if (i == 8) {
            binding.status.text = "Normal"
            binding.status.setTextColor(i)
        } else if (i == 256) {
            binding.status.text = "Overweight"
            binding.status.setTextColor(-256)
        } else{
            binding.status.text = "Obese"
            binding.status.setTextColor(16)
        }
```

Comment: What are the values you pass to the function and what is your expected behavior? It looks like you swapped `wt` and `ft` in the function call too - (inc, wt, ft) instead of (inc, ft, wt) like the function expects

Comment: Wow good eye that solved it. wt is lbs editText and ft is editText of inches and feet.

Comment: Yeah a 5-6 lb person who is 100+ ft tall will have a severely low BMI :) I'm voting to close as "not reproducible or caused by a typo"